# Don't Add Product if Product is already in localStorage

Tags: angular

I have a shopping cart and I only want the products to be set if they don't already exist in localStorage. If the product is already in localStorage, then no new product should be added. Then I need to update the quantity if the item is already set. The code that I have so far sets the product even if the product already exists and it doesn't update the quantity.

```js
public onSubmit(id, thumbnail, quantity, product_name, product_price){

  var data = {
    id,
    thumbnail,
    quantity,
    product_name,
    product_price
  }

  var retrieverObject = localStorage.getItem('items')
  var retrieveObject = JSON.parse(retrieverObject)

  retrieveObject.forEach(el => {
    if (el.id == id) {
      this.quantity += quantity
    } else {
      this.items.push(data)
      localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, JSON.stringify(this.items))
    }
  })
}
```

```
deleteItem(i){
this.items.splice(i,1);
this.setStorageItems(this.items);
console.log("commented out");
}
```

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
<td>
<button type="button" (click)="deleteItem(i)" class="deletebtn">X</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks, Janitha Rasanga. That worked for not setting the item when it's already set. It just doesn't update the quantity.

Comment: When there is nothing in the shopping cart, the onSubmit function doesn't add to the cart any more.

Comment: I added a conditional for an empty array and now it submits when the cart is empty:

 if (retrieverObject === null || retrieverObject === '[]' ) {

Comment: But now that I added the conditional, the item gets added to the cart even if it's already in the cart.

Comment: Added the following conditional but it still adds the product when the product is already in the cart: if (el.id == id && retrieverObject !== '[]' )

Comment: @Janitha Rasanga The item doesn't get added to the cart for the first item that is in the cart but for subsequent items it gets added even if it's already added to the cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done the following way. Have added comments for more clarity

```
// Get the saved stringified object from cache
const retrieverObject: string = localStorage.getItem(this.storageKey) || '';
// Parse it to an array, or set to a blank array, if there is no data
const retrieveObject: Array<any> = retrieverObject ? JSON.parse(retrieverObject) : [];
// Find the item from the array
let presentItem = retrieveObject.find(item => item.id === id);
// Update the data, if the item is found
if (presentItem) {
  this.quantity += quantity;
  // If the stored objects quantity needs to be updated
  presentItem.quantity += quantity;
} else {
  // Else if not found in the saved array, push the new object
  retrieveObject.push(data);
}
// Set the new object to the same key
localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, JSON.stringify(retrieveObject));
```

Update:
Adding my findings from the problems I see with the github code.

1. The storage key is storageKey = 'MyDataStorageKey';
   You have been using the storageKey randomly, placing 'items' as the key in many places. Replace it everywhere with this.storageKey
2. The items array and the localStorage data are being used interchangeably. Make it consistent.
   For example, I can see that you are initializing the items array during ngOnInit() fromt the storage.
   So all the actions (add/edit/delete) should be done over the items array, and when done, just update the storage with the updated items array by calling your setStorageItems()
3. Your question about why the data appears only on page refresh is because, your items is only set on ngOnInit() which is fired only once during component load.

While the above code should have worked based on your question, the other parts of the component have quite a few more errors, which are hampering the flow. I will try to provide the basic code for it start working:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.items = this.getStorageItems();
}
getStorageItems() {
  const retrieverObject: string = localStorage.getItem(this.storageKey) || '';
  return JSON.parse(retrieverObject) || [];
}
setStorageItems(items: any[]) {
  localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, JSON.stringify(items));
}
deleteItem(i){
  this.items.splice(i,1);
  this.setStorageItems(this.items);
}
public onSubmit(id, thumbnail, quantity, product_name, product_price){
  ...
  let presentItem = this.items.find(item => item.id === id);
  if (presentItem) {
    this.quantity += quantity;
    presentItem.quantity += quantity;
  } else {
    this.items.push(data);
  }
  this.setStorageItems(this.items);
}
```

As you already have get/setStorageItems(), don't access it at any other places. Whenever required use those functions to get/set the values.

Use the correct storageKey at all places

This code should resolve your issues. If not, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, Nayak, but I can't add to the cart now and quantity doesn't get updated.

Comment: I don't see any reason why the add should not work. If the item isn't there, the else should get executed. I have put comments, try to debug and see if things aren't going as expected. As for quantity, I had added a piece of commented code, you need to uncomment that.

Comment: I have published my project at https://github.com/makamo66/angular-shopping-cart

Comment: Never mind, I googled debug javascript and found https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Comment: 2 things to note. First, the key being used to get from localStorage is incorrect. And the 2nd thing is you need to uncomment the quantity update line. Also I see that the github code is not the one I have provided. I'm updating the code. You can use as it is.

Comment: The reason that your code is not at github is because it doesn't work. It neither adds a product to the cart nor updates the quantity. You said that you updated the code but when I tried it again it still didn't work.

Comment: Thanks, for all your input, Nayak

Comment: When I refresh the page, the products are in the cart but with the wrong quantities.

Comment: I don't know why it only works after the page refreshes but the reason for the wrong quantities is because my deleteItem code doesn't work properly. I have edited my question to show the deleteItem code.

Comment: When I click delete the item looks like it's deleted but after refreshing the page, the item is still there.

Comment: I edited my question to show the delete button in the HTML.

Comment: When I use location.reload(true);, it forces a reload of the page but that doesn't look good.

Comment: It works when I force a reload of the page but the main problem is the deleteItem function now. It doesn't delete from localStorage.

Comment: I added localStorage.removeItem(i) to the deleteItem function, but it still doesn't remove the item from localStorage.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue with localStorage.removeItem(this.storageKey);

Comment: Now that the page is forced to reload for every submission, the grand total gets reset to null.

Comment: I have added my findings from the github code. Take a look at the issues and the solutions.

Comment: Reloading page in Angular is bad idea. Please avoid it at all costs.

Comment: Thank you Nayak for devoting so much attention to this issue! Unfortunately, I can't try out your code because my localhost isn't working. I shut down the McAfee firewall, re-started my computer and reverted back to the code that had worked before but my localhost still shows a blank page.

Comment: I created a new project and it worked so something must be wrong with my code. Unfortunately, I don't get any error messages but Nayak showed me that my code had a number of errors so I will try to fix those with the help of his input.